# How to print info level to stdout?

Tags: python

How to print info level to stdout ?

```
import logging
import sys
root = logging.getLogger()
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
root.addHandler(ch)

root.info('test1')
root.error('test')
```

result only error level:

```
2013-11-14 11:44:19,675 - root - ERROR - test
```

Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code set the [level of the handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.setLevel), not [logger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel).

Replace following line:

```
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

with:

```
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Answer (score 0):

To give additional Input,

It is something like, when we pass a message to the logger, First check happens if the logger permits the logging level, If allowed it is passed to the Handler1... Handler2, and applies the same logic.